# Reduce memory consumption of mariadb 15.1.41 for micro instance

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-tuning

Running mariadb in micro instance with 600MB memory, and its a very low usage instance and for testing purpose.

Is there a way to reduce the memory consumption for this test database instance?

Tried turning off performance schema and other options available in this link, but still, the memory consumption is about 600 MB.

[Reducing memory consumption of mysql on ubuntu@aws micro instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676753/reducing-memory-consumption-of-mysql-on-ubuntuaws-micro-instance)

Comment: You might like this blog: http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html But it's about MySQL, not MariaDB. I don't consider those two software products to be the same anymore. MariaDB forked in 2010, and has been gradually diverging since then.

Comment: Let's see your my.cnf; I can probably spot some things to decrease.